# target rows immediately after clicked row until a specific row

Tags: jquery

I have this table, all the `.sales-details` rows will be hidden, but when you click on a `.grey` row I want only the `.sales-details` rows immediately after to appear, up until the next `.grey` row. Is this possible with Jquery?

```
<table width="100%" class="modal-table" id="modal-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surgeon name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Antiquity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="grey"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="grey"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="grey"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="sales-details"><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [`.nextUntil(".grey")`](https://api.jquery.com/.nextUntil/)

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It only takes an hour or so, and it pays you that time back immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a click handler to the grey rows (I'd probably make it delegated), then in the handler `this` will refer to the clicked row. You can use [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to select rows following it until a matching selector:

So:

```
$("selector-for-the-table").on("click", "tr.grey", function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".grey").show();
});
```

Example:

```js
$(".modal-table").on("click", "tr.grey", function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".grey").show();
});
```

```css
.modal-table .sales-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="modal-table" id="modal-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Surgeon name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Antiquity</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>grey 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>grey 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>grey 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another option is to group your rows into `tbody` elements, and use `.closest("tbody").next().show()` to show the entire tbody:

```
$("selector-for-the-table").on("click", "tr.grey", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").next().show();
});
```

Example:

```js
$(".modal-table").on("click", "tr.grey", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").next().show();
});
```

```css
.modal-table .tbody-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="modal-table" id="modal-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Surgeon name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Antiquity</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>grey 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="tbody-details">
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>grey 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="tbody-details">
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>grey 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="tbody-details">
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td>detail group 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```